# remove individuals that does not have required order of values for dummy variables? (panel data)

Tags: r

I have panel data and want to keep only the individuals that have x=0 for t=1 and x=1 for t=2  so that:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
    time = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), 
    x = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
)
  ID time x
1  1    1 0
2  1    2 1
3  2    1 0
4  2    2 0
5  3    1 1
6  3    2 1
7  4    1 1
8  4    2 0
```

becomes:

```
  ID time x
1  1    1 0
2  1    2 1
```

trying to get it but don't make it.

Comment: There are more rows that satisfy your condition than your output.

Comment: sorry I missed to say that it is by ID. so it has to be within the same ID number

Comment: So, you only want to keep IDs that have both those cases and throw away the rest?

Comment: yes thats what i want. if individual 2 has x=0 for time=2 and individual 3 has x=1 for time=1 that is not a sequence of x that I want to keep. I want it "conditioned" on individuals if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I expanded your sample data to include more specifically cases where the criteria won't meet for ID 1. You can do this using library `dplyr` and grouped filtering as follows:

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(ID = c(1, 1), time = c(2, 1), x = c(0, 1)))
df
   ID time x
1   1    1 0
2   1    2 1
3   2    1 0
4   2    2 0
5   3    1 1
6   3    2 1
7   4    1 1
8   4    2 0
9   1    2 0
10  1    1 1

# First, get all IDs where both conditions are present
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(any(time == 1 & x == 0) & any(time == 2 & x == 1))
df
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: ID [1]

     ID  time     x
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     1     1     0
2     1     2     1
3     1     2     0
4     1     1     1

# Filter within those IDs for the specific conditions
df %>% filter((time == 1 & x == 0 | time == 2 & x == 1))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: ID [1]

     ID  time     x
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     1     1     0
2     1     2     1
```

Comment: thanks! yes I want the sequence to be only within individuals. so id 2 and 3 does not stay. only ID=1 since that person has the correct values of x